# How to find this probability of these 2 continuous variables?

Tags: probability

> **Problem.**<sup>1)</sup> The joint probability density function of two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ is given by
>
> $$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
> \frac{1}{8}(x+y), & \text{for } 0 \leq x \leq 2, 0 \leq y \leq 2\\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases} $$
>
> Calculate $\mathbf{P}(X + Y \leq 2)$.

---

1) The original image can be seen in https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbmhq.jpg

Comment: thank you all, I am wtill not good at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X+Y\leq 2)=\int_0^{2}\int_0^{2-x} \frac 1 8 (x+y)dydx=\frac 1 8 \int_0^{2} [x(2-x)+\frac {(2-x)^{2}} 2] dx$. Can you continue?

Comment: thank you! all clear now.